# Turn on bounding box individual for every selected object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, bounding-box

Is there way to see bounding box for every selected object individually?

Example: Right now i can only see individual bounding box for text only, but i want to be able select multiple **objects** and see their bounding box.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The second best option would be to use the crop marks effect.

Select all your objects and go to **Effect → Crop Marks**.

[image: sample]

This will add crop marks around each item and since it's an effect, you can easily hide/remove them all at once using the **Appearance Panel** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>).

It isn't the best solution, but it's a quick and simple workaround.

Comment: +1 you inspired me to find a workaround :)

Answer (score 1):

No. The bounding box encompasses all selected objects. The Bounding Box is *not* meant to be a tool for positioning and measurement. Use *guides* and align your circles that way if necessary.

What you are most likely seeing around the text is the *area type box* not the bounding box. While similar, they aren't quite the same thing.

If you want a quick and easy rectangle to see where the corners would fall for circle objects, you can...

- Add a **new Fill** via the **Appearance Panel**
- Highlight and drag the new fill below everything else
- With the new fill highlighted, choose `Effect > Convert to Shape> Rectangle`
- In the dialog box add `Extra width` and `Extra Height` to match the stroke weight of the object.

[image]

That'll give you a solid rectangle and you can see the square the circle occupies. You can then merely remove the extra fill when you are done.

Comment: Thanks for answer, basally there is no such function, i will use then guides

Answer (score 0):

To see the bounding box for the items selected:

Go to view > show edges